# How to configure sequence separator with underscore `_` of friendly_id gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, friendly-id

I am using the `friendly_id gem version 3.3.3.0` in `Rails 3.2`

I have defined friendly id like following :-

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_friendly_id :name, use: :slugged, sequence_separator: '_', max_length: 32

end
```

I have used sequence separator as `_`

but when I execute query on console it was separating using `_`(underscore) but it works fines with `--`(double dash)

I have a 3 user with cached_slug as `user_1` `user_2` and `user_3`

when I am trying to find records with cached slug it generates following query.

using - `_`(underscore)

```
for - `user_1`
User.find("user_1")
SELECT sluggable_id FROM slugs WHERE ((slugs.sluggable_type = 'User' AND slugs.name = 'user_1' AND slugs.sequence = 1)) 
for - `user_2`
User.find("user_2")
SELECT sluggable_id FROM slugs WHERE ((slugs.sluggable_type = 'User' AND slugs.name = 'user_2' AND slugs.sequence = 1)) 
for - `user_3`
User.find("user_3")
SELECT sluggable_id FROM slugs WHERE ((slugs.sluggable_type = 'User' AND slugs.name = 'user_3' AND slugs.sequence = 1))
```

Its not taking sequence from the from the cached slug.

using - `--`(double dash)

```
for - `user--1`
User.find("user--1")
SELECT sluggable_id FROM slugs WHERE ((slugs.sluggable_type = 'User' AND slugs.name = 'user' AND slugs.sequence = 1)) 
for - `user--2`
User.find("user--2")
SELECT sluggable_id FROM slugs WHERE ((slugs.sluggable_type = 'User' AND slugs.name = 'user' AND slugs.sequence = 2)) 
for - `user--3`
User.find("user--3")
SELECT sluggable_id FROM slugs WHERE ((slugs.sluggable_type = 'User' AND slugs.name = 'user' AND slugs.sequence =3))
```

`--`(double dash) identifies the sequence properly

let me know if I am missing anything to include.

**Update - **

I debug gem code and found that it refers to `sequence_separator` as `--` instead of which I have defined in model that is `_`

```
class String
  def parse_friendly_id(separator = nil)
    separator ||= FriendlyId::Configuration::DEFAULTS[:sequence_separator]
    name, sequence = split(/#{Regexp.escape(separator)}(\d+)?\z/)
    return name, (sequence ||= 1).to_i
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't understand the issue?  It is using the sequence seperator when creating a slug.  For your "cached slugs" it then uses the slug name it created. So for `user_1` it looks for a slug with the name of `user_1`

Comment: Can you explain more what the "cached_slug" is?  Those queries look like they're working fine.

Comment: @j-dexx I have updated my question. for `user_1` it should search slug name as `user` and and sequence number `1`  and for `user_2` it should search slug name as `user` and and sequence number `2` and so on..

Comment: @MaxWilliams `cached_slug` column is use to store the latest slug.